# gcc -E -dM gives me preprocessor defines but I want it to compile

Tags: gcc

I have a large source directory with a complicated Makefile structure (lots of includes etc.)

I would like to grab the preprocessor defines that gcc will provide when you run

gcc -E -dM. However, I also want the source to be built. And when I check the make/build log, I'd like to see all the commands that were run by make, and ALSO the #defines from all the files in the source that were passed to the compiler and/or overriden.

I'm not sure how to go about this.

For e.g

If had a file foo.c with just this one line

`#define PI 3.14`

Running gcc -E -dM foo.c will print out all the preprocessory defines to stdout, as well as the define inside foo.c.

But it does not compile. How do I combine commands such that both things happen?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this in two passes, but you can probably set up a makefile rule to do it, e.g. for compiling C code:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -dM -E $< > $<.dump  # dump all preprocessor symbols to .dump file
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@          # compile to .o as normal
```

Alternatively if you want to separate the build and preprocessing you could have two rules, e.g.

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@          # compile to .o as normal

%.dump: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -dM -E $< > $<.dump  # dump all preprocessor symbols to .dump file
```

You would also need a fake target to ensure that all the .c files generate .dump files.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I will give this a shot. Where does the .dump file get created? Will I find it in the cwd from where I ran make (top level)?

Comment: @Rohan: it should be in the same directory as the .c file

Comment: Thanks Paul. That worked very well on a small example I created with a simple foo.c file. The problem I'm trying to solve is slightly more complex. I have a folder with the .c files, but the compile into .o is being taken care of in a different make file. I tried just the first part of the solution you gave me (with the -dM switches etc.) but the rule doesn't seem to trigger, because now in this case, I don't care for the compile per se since its being taken care of.
How should I modify the above rule such that, it runs inside a folder of interest on all .c files and gives me those symbols?

Comment: @Rohan: see edit above about separating the build from the preprocessing. I think you're probably going to have to get your hands dirty though and start reading the GNU make manual and generally learning about makefiles etc.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Yes, this is fairly new to me. I completely agree with your recommendation. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: @PaulR do you conclusively know that the preprocessing and compilation cannot be output in the same execution? Preprocessing is necessary for compilation i.e. it's done anyway during compilation; shouldn't it be possible for `gcc` to output both?

Comment: @Adrian: I don't see any obvious way, but I've never really tried to do both simultaneously.

Comment: I have tried it exactly as described but my *.dump files are just empty.

Comment: @Daniel: I just checked with a simple makefile and both of the methods in the answer above seem to work as expected. What version of gcc are you using ? Can you perhaps post a new question (with a link to this question) and including a [mcve] ?

Comment: @PaulR I'm using Cygwin with GCC 7.4.0. When I duplicate the compiler call in the makefile and add the parameters "-E -dM" the created .dump files were empty. But when I run the GCC manually with an empty input file (e.g. "gcc -E -dM empty.c > macros.dump") then it successfully creates the macro list.

Comment: @Daniel: I think I’d need to see the whole makefile to make any further suggestions - maybe include it as part of a new question?